# Getting Serious Application Error With Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I got the following error when deleting an object from my app.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

I'm still trying to recreate the process to find out exactly where it is crashing.

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x5adc8b0 <x-coredata://2B90C6EC-E046-4508-A1B1-6C4B19BF830D/Session/p1>' with userInfo {
NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
        "<Session: 0x6f7c830> (entity: Session; id: 0x5adc8b0 <x-coredata://2B90C6EC-E046-4508-A1B1-6C4B19BF830D/Session/p1> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x5adc8b0 <x-coredata://2B90C6EC-E046-4508-A1B1-6C4B19BF830D/Session/p1>''
```

Comment: When a object is deleted and before inserting the data back into the core data it is always advisable to clear the existing NSFetchedResultsController cache if you are using one.
This is applicable only incase you are using the NSFetchedResultsController for loading some kind of table view [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Cache"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A)** If you are subscribing to save notifications, Core Data is pointing to a failure there.

**B)** The "could not fulfill a fault" message is often related to deleting an object, after which some other part of your app tries to access ANY property on it.  Yes, even ones where faults were previously fulfilled.  The whole object is unusable after a delete.

Comment: Thanks, it must be B because I am not using any notifications.  Any ideas on how to track down where this fault may be?

Comment: Add a general Exception breakpoint and start from there... also in the exception you get from CoreData, print out the UserInfo part of the exception as it will usually have more details.

Comment: Thanks Kendall. I'll try that.  One thing, how can I print out the userInfo part?  Also, is your website down?  I wanted to find some contact info because a I had a question for you.

Comment: This error is usually caused by retaining a referece to a managed object somewhere other than the context and then deleting it from the context e.g. you put the MO in array, which retains it, and then you delete it from the context. Then you try to access the MO or one of its relationships in context but the context no longer thinks the object exist.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred in my code when I passed a managed object down to a custom NSOperation class.  My NSOperation would load other objects through its to-many relationship, process them, then delete those objects.  If it tried to do a search on more objects in the to-many relationship, it would sometimes crash with the "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" exception.  Then I remembered reading about "thread confinement" in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW2) so I changed my code to pass a key down to my NSOperation class.  The NSOperation class would then do its own search in its own context to find its own instance of the core data class.  I stopped getting the exception after that.  (I still have to use save notifications.)